# generator imbedded in list

Tags: python, list, constructor

My code

```
yValues = [3, 6, 12]
retVal = []
for num in range(2):
    retVal.append((num),(Y for Y in range( math.ceil(yValues[num]-yVaules[num-1]) )) )
```

what I'd like this to return is the list

```
retVal[(0, 3), (0, 4), (0, 5), (0, 6), (1, 6), (1, 7), (1, 8), (1, 9), (1, 10), (1, 11), (1, 12)]
```

I haven't worked with constructors in a while, cause right now I'm just getting

```
retVal[(0, constructorFunction at ...), (1, constructorFunction at ...)]
```

Comment: Please test the code you paste in before submitting. You have a case issue with your variable and errors in your append statement.

Comment: What is the matter with 'one line solutions'? Take it easy!

Answer (score 1):

Use `extend` instead of `append` to extend the list with all the elements from the generator instead of appending the generator itself. (Also, a few more smaller problems.)

```
yValues = [3, 6, 12]
retVal = []
for num in range(1, len(yValues)):
    retVal.extend((num,Y) for Y in range(math.ceil(yValues[num]-yValues[num-1])))
print(retVal)
```

Your `range` went from `0` to `2` (exclusive), so you compared the `0`th to the `-1`th (the last) element. Instead, you probably want to loop from `1` to the `len(yValues)` (again, exclusive) and compare those.

Edit: If you want the inner loop to include the value of the next index, add one to the upper limit of the `range` (remember: The upper limit is *exclusive*).

```
range(math.ceil(yValues[num]-yValues[num-1]) + 1)
```

Comment: so this returns `[(1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5)]` but if possible I'd rather have it return `[(1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6)]`

Comment: nm, i know what i've done wrong, I think i can fix this myself